# Rewrite shell script with GNU Parallel to Python

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a shell script that uses GNU Parallel to run function in parallel. Now, I am rewriting the script to Python and I dont know, how to do this correctly.

In script, I have:

```
parallel --jobs 5 --linebuffer run {1} ::: "${files[@]}"
```

How can I convert this to Python code? In shell, `files` is an array of files, `run` method calls external program that process the file.

In Python, I have method `def run(file)`, that have several Python command to prepare data and at the end, it calls external program with `os.command`.

```
def run(file):
  do something with input file
  os.command(...)
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 not exactly. I dont want to use `Popen`. I have `run` method in python, and inside this method is `os.command`. Threading seems more reasonable, but I dont know whether to use it or multiprocessing. Also, I dont know, hot to pass the array of files.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `Popen`?

Comment: How can I call Python method with Popen?

Comment: Note that processes will be created anyway using the `os.command` call. Creating processes for calling internal Python methods using Popen is not great though because it is often too low level. Using [processing pools (eg with map)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is often simpler and better. If you know that your processing is IO bound and written in Python, then threads are better (due to the GIL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use multiprocessing :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run(file):
  do something with input file
  os.command(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(run, sys.argv[1:])
```

Call it with :

```
python test.py "${files[@]}"
```